# "Letters and Numbers" Numbers game

Tags: nt.number-theory

On the TV channel SBS, in Australia, there is a TV show in which contestants have six numbers and the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division with which to produce a three digit number.

My question is whether, for any 6 numbers, this is always possible, and if so, does it hold for any choice of 6 single digit numbers? What is the lower bound on how many numbers are required?

EDIT: The numbers must all be different. So (1,1,1,1,1,1) and (1,1,1,99,99,99) aren't allowed.

Comment: Given 1,1,1,1,1,1, I don't think you can get higher than 9, so no. You can experiment here http://www.crosswordtools.com/numbers-game/

Comment: Ed Pegg Jr. wrote on the "one complexity" of a number, which is the least number of ones needed to produce the number where only addition and multiplication are allowed.  The least complex number greater than 100 is qpi which takes 13 ones to produce in this way.  Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory has some more on this problem.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.07  

Comment: Sorry, I meant any six numbers subject to the restrictions on the show, so six different numbers. So the 6-tuple (1,1,1,1,1,1) is not allowed.

Comment: qpi is smartphone for 108.  Gerhard "Wants A Bigger, Smarter Keyboard" Paseman, 2011.06.07 

Comment: 6 is the minimum, as suggested by the set 0,1,2,3,4,5. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.07 

Comment: I'd interpret "2 digits" in the problem as meaning a number between 10 and 99, not something like 05.

Comment: @Gerhard: Is there a proof of that?

Comment: With the one- and two-digit restrictions, suppose we have 1,1,1,99,99,99. What 3-digit number can you get? 99 (99/99+1+1+1)=365. Are we required to use all the numbers?

Comment: @Gerald: You are not required to use all the numbers, but you can only use each number once. Also each number must be different.

Comment: As I read the question, the solver is required only to produce a number greater than 99:  The product of any 5 positive numbers will do this.  If instead you are asking that any number in the ramge 100-999 be produced, then you will likely need more digits.  Robert Israel's post suggests to me that at least 7 numbers are needed.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.07

Comment: Again, I should not use a small screen for this.  The product of any 5 positive distinct integers is greater than 119.  Gerhard "Wants A Bigger Screen Too" Paseman, 2011.06.07 

Comment: Wait: the 3-digit goal is given in advance? or not?

Comment: I read the OP's question as having the 3-digit goal given in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the six numbers are all distinct, and each must be used exactly once.  A brute-force program found, e.g. that with the six numbers 4, 6, 8, 16, 32, 64 the possible results did not include 571, 581, 587, 619, 623, 631, 649, 657, 661, 671, 673, 679, 681, 695, 709, 713, 721, 731, 743, 793, 811, 817, 821, 823, 827, 839, 841, 845, 849, 851, 853, 855, 857, 859, 863, 865, 871, 873, 877, 878, 879, 881, 887, 905, 911, 913, 917, 919, 921, 923, 933, 935, 937, 941, 943, 979, 983, 985, 987, 991, or 993.

Comment: Robert: my favourite version of this question involves making 24 out of 8,3,8,3 (and you have to use all the digits). The answer is 8/(3-(8/3)), and you have to leave the world of the integers to find this. Did you allow for such possibilities with your program? 

Comment: @Robert: Each number CAN be used once, but does not have to be.

Comment: @Shannon: Robert's suggestion of 4, 6, 18, 32, 64 cannot produce 571, even if each number does not necessarily have to be used once. I didn't do the math, but rather used Granger's link above: http://www.crosswordtools.com/numbers-game/

Comment: Robert: see also 7,7,3,3 to make 24. It's 7*(3+3/7).

Answer (score 1):

The answers to the MathOverflow question entitled "Optimal Countdown" might be of interest.  One poster has results where certain tuples of 6 numbers can yield more than the answers from 1 to 1000.
(Link may be provided by some helpful soul without a phone-sized screen.)

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.06.07

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61034/optimal-countdown

Answer (score 1):

To resolv this kind of problem there is a program CEB you can find [here](http://gilles.bannay.free.fr/jeux_us.html)